# How to Shape Textboxes and Panels in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How can I shape Text boxes and Panels in windows form? Is there any designing tactic other than properties showing in the windows... Using available properties i am not able to create custom shapes, help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom shaped text box in windows forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749464/custom-shaped-text-box-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [winform](/questions/tagged/winform) TextBoxes dont expose a Paint event you would need to do it in WPF and use an ElementHost, [here is a WPF Shaped Textbox example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483215/wpf-custom-shape-control).

Here is an example to shape a Panel:

[image]

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

    Dim panelPath As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

    ' Set a new rectangle to the same size as the button's  
    ' ClientRectangle property. 
    Dim newRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)


    ' Decrease the size of the rectangle.
    newRectangle.Inflate(-10, -10)

    ' Draw the button's border. 
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, newRectangle)

    'Increase the size of the rectangle to include the border.
    newRectangle.Inflate(1, 1)

    ' Create a circle within the new rectangle.
    panelPath.AddEllipse(newRectangle)
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, panelPath)
    ' Set the button's Region property to the newly created  
    ' circle region.
    Panel1.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(panelPath)


End Sub
```

[MSDN Ref: Control.Region Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx)